# TinyXML parsing a string in XML format returns NULL?

Tags: tinyxml

I'm trying to use TinyXML to parse a string with XML format. But the return pointer is always NULL. I'm not sure which part of code is setting wrong.

```
TiXmlDocument docTemp;
const string strData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><Hello>World</Hello>";
const char* pTest = docTemp.Parse(strData.c_str(), 0 , TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8);
if(pTest == NULL){
    cout << "pTest is NULL" << endl;
}
```

It always shows 'pTest is NULL'
Any idea?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the parse returns null on success.

Can you see if docTemp.RootElement() contains a valid element ?

Answer (score 4):

It should return 0 in the case of an error but looks like there is bug in TiXmlBase::SkipWhiteSpace, if there is no character after the closing bracket it returns 0, but if there is a white space or \r or \n it returns the pointer. So you have 2 options add some white character after the closing bracket or modify the following lines in at the beginning of SkipWhiteSpace:

```
if ( !p || !*p )
{
    return 0;
}
```

to something like:

```
if ( !p )
{
   return 0;
}
if (!*p)
{
   return p;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(pTest == NULL && docTemp->Error() ){
        cout << "pTest is NULL" << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `TiXMLDocument::Parse` returns `NULL`in the case of failure and the pointer to the character next to closing angle bracket, when parsing was succesful.